# Firefox add-on install by clicking on link

Tags: php, html, header, firefox-addon, mime-types

Here is my php code that is called when a user clicks on link: http://www.example.com/?page=install_my_ext.php:

```
if ( preg_match("/Firefox/", $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']) ) {   
       // send file
    $fname = 'myext.xpi';
    // $fname = 'test.pdf';
    header('Content-type: application/x-xpinstall'); 
    //header('Content-type: application/pdf'); 
    header("Content-Disposition: inline; filename='$fname'"); 
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
    readfile($fname);               
}
else {
    header("Content-type: text/html\n\n");
    echo "Firefox required";    
}
```

Firefox popups "Allow" dialog and when allowed reports that add-on cannot be installed because it is corrupted. 
When I install add-on from Add-on menu through "Install Add-on from file", my addon perfectly installs. That means, there is a problem with file transfer.
When I send a PDF file with the code above (uncommenting $fname='test.pdf' and Content-type=application/pdf), the result is ok: pdf is displayed as expected.

Where is an error?

Comment: I'd go for adding a content-length header: header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($fname));

Comment: Tried. Does not help.